# How do i use abstraction to modify this class so it shows both colors of keys?

Tags: abstraction, greenfoot

So  Currently, our Key class can only produce white keys.  This is because I have hard-coded the file names of the key images ("white-key.png" and "white-key-down.png").  How do I use abstraction to modify the Key class so that it can show either white or black keys?

```
import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, and Greenfoot)

public class Key extends Actor
{
    private boolean isDown;
    private String key;
    private String sound;
    /**
     * Create a new key.
     */
    public Key(String keyName, String soundFile)
    {  
       key = keyName;
       sound = soundFile;
    }

    /**
     * Do the action for this key.
     */
    public void act()
    {
        if ( !isDown && Greenfoot.isKeyDown(key)) 
        {
            play();
            setImage("white-key-down.png");
            isDown = true;
        }
        if ( isDown && !Greenfoot.isKeyDown(key))
        {
            setImage("white-key.png");
            isDown = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Play the note of this key.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        Greenfoot.playSound(sound);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want *different* classes that have different images, rather than an option for changing the image within the same class.

There are several ways to do this; here's a simple one just to give you an idea:

```
import greenfoot.*;  // (World, Actor, GreenfootImage, and Greenfoot)

abstract public class Key extends Actor
{
    private boolean isDown;
    private String key;
    private String sound;

    abstract String getImageFileName();
    abstract String getDownImageFileName();

    /**
     * Create a new key.
     */
    public Key(String keyName, String soundFile)
    {  
       key = keyName;
       sound = soundFile;
    }

    /**
     * Do the action for this key.
     */
    public void act()
    {
        if ( !isDown && Greenfoot.isKeyDown(key)) 
        {
            play();

            String image = getDownImageFileName();
            setImage(image);

            isDown = true;
        }
        if ( isDown && !Greenfoot.isKeyDown(key))
        {
            String image = getImageFileName();
            setImage(image);
            isDown = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Play the note of this key.
     */
    public void play()
    {
        Greenfoot.playSound(sound);
    }
}
```

Then you can add new classes, each with its own image:

```
public class WhiteKey extends Key
{
    @Override
    String getImageFileName()
    {
        return "white-key.png";
    }

    @Override
    String getDownImageFileName()
    {
        return "white-key-down.png";
    }
}

public class BlackKey extends Key
{
    @Override
    String getImageFileName()
    {
        return "black-key.png";
    }

    @Override
    String getDownImageFileName()
    {
        return "black-key-down.png";
    }
}
```